# EV3 connection problem via USB on Windows 8.1

Tags: ev3, lejos

I am using LEGO EV3 on windows 8.1 eclipse Neon. When I try to launch the class as a LeJos application I get this error.

```
IP address is /10.0.1.1
Creating the jar file or uploading the program failed
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Caused by java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
See Eclipse error log for detailed stack trace.
Creating the jar file or uploading the program failed
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Caused by java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
See Eclipse error log for detailed stack trace.
```

Comment: I would suggest asking on the LeJOS forum: https://lejos.sourceforge.io/forum/viewforum.php?f=18

Comment: I suspect that you can't use it with this version of Windows. It's not compatible. Try using another version of Windows.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't help with general support for this kind of thing.